# can we read pdf file available on the mobile device using appium android

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I want to validate the text written in the pdf file for that first i thing i
need to read the data from the pdf file is there is any way to do that 
note:  File is available in the mobile device

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Java along with your Appium tests, you may try [pdf-util](https://github.com/vinsguru/pdf-util). This library supports comparison of PDF files in both visual and textual modes.

First get your PDF text:

```
import com.testautomationguru.utility.PDFUtil;

PDFUtil pdfUtil = new PDFUtil();

//returns the pdf content - all pages
String pdfText = pdfUtil.getText("/path/to/file.pdf");
```

Then in order to compare to expected text:

```
pdfText.contains(..
```

or

```
pdfText.matches(..
```

In order to access your PDF file on the device, you may try [pull-file](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/device/files/pull-file/).

// Java

`byte[] pdfFile = driver.pullFile("/internal storage/downloads/filename.pdf");`

Comment: how to find the path of the file available on the mobile device

Comment: my file is in internal storage/downloads/filename.pdf so you mean i need to use like byte[] fileBase64 = driver.pullFile("/internal storage/downloads/filename.pdf");

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of both pdf-utl and pull-file, then try these libraries in your code and update your question with more practical points.